# How do I use a session for my login screen?

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I am creating a webshop and I have the login working but I ran into a problem. I need to use sessions in order to display and hide certain pages. It's a login screen for the backend of my webshop so it makes sense that it should be secured and hidden from people who aren't allowed to access the backend. I know that I need to start a session at the top of the pagebut then what? I searched Google but I can't find a solution wich I can apply to my code.

```
<?php
session_start();

*my information*

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$wwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Medewerkers WHERE medewerker_username='$uname' && medewerker_password='$wwoord'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result) {
    $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
    echo"U bent ingelogd!";
    header("location: index.php");

} else {
    echo "Inloggegevens incorrect.";
}
}
?>

<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Admin panel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tables.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Admin panel</a></li>
<li><a href="Medewerkersoverzicht.php">Medewerkersoverzicht</a></li>
<li><a href="addMedewerker.php">Medewerkers toevoegen</a></li>
<li><a href="Klantenoverzicht.php">Klantenoverzicht</a></li>
<li><a href="Productoverzicht.php">Productoverzicht</a></li>
<li><a href="addProduct.php">Product toevoegen</a></li>
<li><a href="reparatieOverzicht.php">Reparatieoverzicht</a></li>
<li><a href="contactoverzicht.php">Contactoverzicht</a></li>
</ul>
<h1>Admin login</h1>
<form role="form" method="post" action="index.php" class="contactForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" class="" id="username">      <br><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="wachtwoord" class=""    id="wachtwoord"><br><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Inloggen</button><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Just check $_SESSION['ingelogd'] is true then show screen else redirect to login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the session is started check for the existence of the session variable- if it already exists then redirect the user.

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

/* if the session already exists, redirect user */
if( isset( $_SESSION['ingelogd'] ) ) header("location: index.php");

/* don't echo content outwith the document body ~ other than suitable head content */

$msg='';
$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname );
if ( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed");/* don't reveal too much information about db ! */


if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $wwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Medewerkers WHERE medewerker_username='$uname' && medewerker_password='$wwoord'";

    /* best practise: don't mix OO & procedural code */
    $result = $conn->query( $query );

    if( $result ) {
        $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
        header("location: index.php");
    } else {
        /* assign error message as a variable to echo later */
        $msg="Inloggegevens incorrect.";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Admin panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Admin panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="Medewerkersoverzicht.php">Medewerkersoverzicht</a></li>
                <li><a href="addMedewerker.php">Medewerkers toevoegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="Klantenoverzicht.php">Klantenoverzicht</a></li>
                <li><a href="Productoverzicht.php">Productoverzicht</a></li>
                <li><a href="addProduct.php">Product toevoegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="reparatieOverzicht.php">Reparatieoverzicht</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactoverzicht.php">Contactoverzicht</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h1>Admin login</h1>
            <?php
                echo $msg;/* error message */
            ?>
            <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php" class="contactForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" class="" id="username"><br><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="wachtwoord" class="" id="wachtwoord"><br><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Inloggen</button><br></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well it's  a great piece of code but I have a problem.. It says the following: "This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: @Lucafraser it is because you redirect to index.php while you're in index.php . It is stated in `if( isset( $_SESSION['ingelogd'] ) ) header("location: index.php");`

Comment: So what do you suggest? Create a new page? Or what should I do?

Comment: apolgies for slow response... i saw, in your code, the redirect to `index.php` and assumed, probably incorrectly, that the login form was separate to the index page. What is the name of the login page - is it index.php or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just coverting @Divyesh Savaliya 's comment into code.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['ingelogd'])){ ?>
// ... the rest of your code in index.php
<?php } else {
header('location: login.php'); // if your login page is login.php
}?>
```

actually, since you don't fill the session if login fails, it is better to store some information about the user (such as the username or user id) in the session and check using `isset` instead of storing boolean in the session.
you will want this value later.